# Xamarin.Forms SQLite CreateTableAsync() return type usage

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to find out what is going on under the hood with my table after I call the CreateTableAsync method.

 I'm using the sqlite-net-pcl NuGet (for a Xamarin.Forms project).

```
public async Task<int> CreatePartnersTableAsync()
{
    var tablesCreated = await _efContext.CreateTableAsync<Partner>();

    var result = tablesCreated.Results[typeof(Partner)];

    return result;
}
```

This code should create a new Partner table if it doesn't exist. If it does exist, it should hook the connection up to it. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Now to my question:


What would the returning integer mean?

It can be either 1 or 0.


Does 0 mean that the table **was not** created successfully?

... or does it mean that the table **was there beforehand** and the connection **was not attached to that table successfully**?


Does 1 mean that the table **was** created successfully?

... or does it mean that the table **was there beforehand** and the connection **was attached to that table successfully**?

Thank you.

Comment: You can probably just do some rudementary debugging to determine the answer to this. As far as I can tell, there's no indepth documentation that explicitly tells you what the result means exactly. But just create a few unit tests and determine it for yourself, there's not exactly a lot of combinations that it CAN be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Assumption**: As it is not specified in question I am assuming you are using [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)

This was a known [bug](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/461) which was fixed in latest version. A quick look at this [pull](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/commit/d96e30fa916ac5ccd96df7260e5b1eea36d4f9ba) request for this [feature](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/541) would clarify.

With the latest version your code should return `CreateTableResult` enum - which should appropriately indicate whether table was created successfully.

**EDIT 1**

Looks this feature hasn't been released yet. You will have to either wait for next stable release (> 1.4.118), or use the beta version 1.5.xxx-beta.

At this point, without the bug fix/feature, the return value is not valid.

**EDIT 2**

Just to clarify, even with the update, it will tell you whether the table already existed or not. There is a subtle difference. If there is an error encountered during creation/migration, I would expect an exception to be thrown.

Comment: Your assumption was almost right - I'm using sqlite-net-pcl - sorry for not mentioning it, I will update my question so it's clear. I am using the latest stable version. However the CreateTableResult is a class that has only one property - Result. It is of type Dictionary<Type, int>, no enum there as far as i can see.

Comment: I guess it is not released yet - if not, according to the bug - I guess it will always return 1. Let me see if I can spin up a quick project to test.

Comment: so in other words - for now there is no way to tell (looking at the CreateTableAsync returning int) whether the Table was created successfully or whatever happened to it. Is that right?

Comment: Even with the update - it will tell you whether the table already existed or not. There is a subtle difference. If there is an error encountered during creation/migration, I would expect an exception to be thrown.